# bootstrap 4.1 last child in input group loses rounded corners if validation involved

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4.1 last child in input group loses rounded corners if validation involved

see example [Custom styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#custom-styles)

Is there an elegant workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bootstrap class `rounded-right`. It rounds the borders. Add it to the `input` or `select` or whatever you want to make round.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is to create a class based on defined `@mixin` and `_variables`, but it should be `!important` to overthrow `:not(:last-child)` structure. Like so:

```
.border-right-radius{
    @include border-right-radius($border-radius !important);
}
```

In my case, I put it next to `input-group-text` to overwrite styles for `.input-group > .input-group-append:not(:last-child) > .input-group-text`.